# Some config options ignored when building a Rust program that uses Rocket-rs in a container

Tags: docker, rust, rust-rocket

I have a very strange issue with my Rust program that uses the rocket-rs library.

The issue I am facing is that when I try and build my program in a Docker container using a `Dockerfile` I created, some parts of the config I set out in the `rocket.toml` file is not applied. More specifically, I have set the `log level` option to `critical` in the config file and that is working but the `address` option I have set in the config file is not applied.

What is wierd is that I can build and all the options are applied on my local machine properly but not in the container.

Output when I build and run the program on my machine (no docker):

```
Configured for release.
   >> address: 0.0.0.0
   >> port: 8000
   >> workers: 12
   >> ident: Rocket
   >> keep-alive: 5s
   >> limits: bytes = 8KiB, data-form = 2MiB, file = 1MiB, form = 32KiB, json = 1MiB, msgpack = 1MiB, string = 8KiB
   >> tls: disabled
   >> temp dir: C:\Users\Nlanson\AppData\Local\Temp\
   >> log level: critical
   >> cli colors: true
   >> shutdown: ctrlc = true, force = true, grace = 2s, mercy = 3s
```

Output when I build and run the program in a docker container:

```
Configured for release.
   >> address: 127.0.0.1    //This is what I do not want
   >> port: 8000
   >> workers: 2
   >> ident: Rocket
   >> keep-alive: 5s
   >> limits: bytes = 8KiB, data-form = 2MiB, file = 1MiB, form = 32KiB, json = 1MiB, msgpack = 1MiB, string = 8KiB
   >> tls: disabled
   >> temp dir: /tmp
   >> log level: critical
   >> cli colors: true
   >> shutdown: ctrlc = true, force = true, signals = [SIGTERM], grace = 2s, mercy = 3s
```

Here is the Dockerfile I am using:

```
FROM rust as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release

FROM rust as runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/server .
COPY --from=builder /app/database.db .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["./server"]
```

and my rocket config file:

```
[global]
#address is not applied
address = "0.0.0.0"
#log level is applied
log_level = "critical"
```

I have tried a few things to trouble shoot this issue:

- Run the container with `docker run -it <container name> bash` and check that all the required files including the config file is copied into the container
- Build the program in the container through bash using different options.

Please let me know if I am missing any details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You say that you checked that the file is copied to the container, but I do not see any line that would copy `Rocket.toml` to the `runtime` image. Are you sure?

Comment: My bad I did not clarify. The ```COPY . .``` line copies the directory containing the project which includes ```Rocket.toml```

Comment: Yes, to the first container. But as you use a multi-stage build, your final image ends up with only the "server" binary and the database. However, Rocket.toml is required during runtime, not at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create environment variable named ROCKET_ADDRESS in dockerfile. I am sharing an example

```
ENV_ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["./server"]
```